# How to send text to syslog-ng server

Tags: networking, syslog

I am try to find the simplest way to send text from Linux to syslog-ng server.
I have tried few things:

```
curl -d "my data heure" -X POST server:port
```

and

```
cat bootlog | netcat server port port
```

This works, except it hangs.

I want to setup a script to automatically send data to syslog-ng. I am unable to install syslog-ng on my client side, this is why I am trying to find a work around.

I was thinking about using a "&"  at the end of my request (`curl -d "my data heure" -X POST server:port &`), but I am not sure it is a good idea.

Can someone help with is issue,

Best Regards.

dmx

Comment: I haven't used _syslog-ng_ and I am _not_ expert on logging, but a Google search suggests that the `loggen` command can do this: https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/administration-guide/87

Comment: Read `man logger`.

Answer (score 1):

### Local test on syslog-ng server

**First terminal window** will continuously display received syslog messages:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

or when many syslog traps will be received:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep "This is only test message"
```

**Second terminal** send testing message to server itself:

```
logger -p 0 "This is only test message -----"
```

You shoud see the message received by syslog in first terminal:

```
May 11 21:23:13 YourServerName YourUserName: This is only test message -----
```

### Message sending from remote node

Let the address of your syslog server be e.g. `192.168.20.5`

```
logger -p 0 -n 192.168.20.5 "This is only test message ----- remote"
```

If everything is set up correctly, you will see the received message on the server.

### Troubleshooting

If the message does not arrive via network, check the listening UDP port 514 on the server and the allowing rule on the firewall:

```
sudo netstat -lnup | grep 514
sudo iptables-save

sudo iptables-save | grep 514
```

The `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf` file must be checked too whether the Sources, Destinations and Paths sections are set for receiving traps via network.